# the general form of SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Why do various SDE books consider only equations with the following form:

$$\displaystyle \mathrm {d} X_{t}=\mu (X_{t},t)\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (X_{t},t)\,\mathrm {d} B_{t}$$

I understand that it is analytical and computational convenient, and also many time-varying phenomena in various fields in science and engineering can be modeled as the above form. But I still wonder

1. What is the exact reason that we just assume SDE with this form?
2. Can you give me some examples of SDE that do not fall into the above form? Are they solvable?
3. Are there any textbooks that consider other forms?

Comment: What other form would you suggest - what form is not there in your view?

Comment: For example, I think multiple noise sources 

$\displaystyle \mathrm {d} X_{t}=\mu (X_{t},t)\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (X_{t},t)\,  (\mathrm {d} B_{t} + dC_t)$

or higher order:

$\displaystyle \mathrm {d} X_{t}=\mu (X_{t},t)\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (X_{t},t)\,  \mathrm {d}^2 B_{t}$

And also instead of noise-ODE, I think that SDE with PDE is also possible.

(Since I'm a noob in differential equations, please understand me for silly question)

Comment: I guess that multi-dimensional Brownian Motion is not much of a stretch from first order. There is certainly a research literature on stochastic PDE's, integration with respect to more general processes (Poisson and so on) and even quantum stochastic processes. As you suggest, this may currently require too much machinery for a textbook and someone has to have the time to write one too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remaind that $\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$ is a notation for the stochastic integral
$$
\int_0^t \sigma(s,X_s)dW_s
$$
There is no good way to define the term $d^2 W_t$.

SPDES instead are the infinite dimensional generalization of  the formula that you have written.

The most famous example is the stochastic heat equation

$$
\partial_t u= \Delta u + \xi
$$
where $\xi$ is the [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)

More generally one can define as SPDE as

$$
dx_t=L x_t +F(x_t) dt +Q dW_t
$$
where $L$ is the generator of a $C_0$ semigroup on a separable Banach space $B$, $F$ is measurable in $\mathcal{D}(F) \subseteq B$, $Q : K \to B$ is a bounded linear operator form an Hilbert space $K$ to $B$ and $W_t$ is a cylindrical B.M. see e.g [these lecture notes](https://www.hairer.org/)  on the subject.

Many of these condition can be probably lifted as well *e.g* you can consider multiplicative noise $Q(x_t) dW_t$, or you can consider integration w.r. to non Gaussian measures, but these are actually research topics and I'm not expecting to see that in any textbook (so far at least)